# No method matching error when working with Vector{Int64]

Tags: dataframe, function, vector, type-conversion, julia

I have the following code where firstly I add the values for each index from two columns and creating Vector{Int64}

```
df = CSV.read(joinpath("data", "data.csv"), DataFrame)
adding_columns = df.firstcolumn + df.secondcolumn
```

Then I will create a function as following:

```
function fnct(data::Vector{T}; var= 8) where { T <: Number }
V = []
for x in 1:size(data)[1]
    strt = x-var
    ending = x+var
    avg = 0
    if strt < 1
        for y in 1:x+var
           avg  =  avg+data[y]
        end
        avg = avg/(x+var-1)
    elseif  ending >  size(data)[1]
        for y in x-var:size(data)[1]
           avg  =  avg+data[y]
        end
        avg = avg/(size(data)-x-var)
    else
        for y in x-var:x+var
           avg  =  avg+data[y]
        end 
        avg = avg/(2*var)
    end
    push!(V,avg)
    
end
return V
```

end

When trying:

```
typeof(adding_columns)
```

I will get:

```
Vector{Int64}
```

however when calling

```
fnct(adding_columns)
```

I will get:

> ERROR: MethodError: no method matching -(::Tuple{Int64}, ::Int64)

I presume that it takes my adding_columns as Tuple but I do not get it why, when the typeof is giving me Vector.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: What does the body of your function look like? Looks like it's trying to subtract an integer from a tuple, but it's not clear where the tuple comes from

Comment: It is taking the values of the vector, and creating new vector with smoothened values. I take the average of neighbor values and setting it as the new value instead of original value. I am not manipulating with the original vector, just saving the averages to the new vector. 
I initialize new vector as V = []. Can the problem be there?

Comment: I added the body of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size(data)` is a tuple:

```
julia> size([1,2,3]::Vector{Int})
(3,)
```

...but you're subtracting an integer from it in `avg = avg/(size(data)-x-var)`.

Did you mean `avg = avg/(length(data)-x-var)` or `avg = avg/(size(data, 1)-x-var)`?

Comment: Thank you very much it works, sorry for my rookie mistake.